# Using Pear Mail to mail with attachment

Tags: php, email

I have a script I run to send emails with attachments.
On my old server it worked perfectly, But since moving a few days back. The script no longer works. As soon as it is supposed to send a mail, it bombs out.

I did find this error in the error log file,How can I locate the problem?

```
[08-Jul-2015 12:39:17 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mime_content_type() in /home/username/public_html/editor/cronjob.php on line 79
```

My code more or less looks like the below:

```
function sendmailwithattachment($from,$to,$subject,$body,$host,$username,$password,$body_id,$port) {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `email_attachments` where `email_id`='$body_id';";
        if($result = mysqli_query($this->link, $query)){
            if($result->num_rows!=0){
                 $headers = array ('From' => $from, 'To' => $to, 'Subject' => $subject);
                 $crlf = "\n";
                 $mime = new Mail_mime($crlf);
                 $mime->setHTMLBody($body);
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,1)) {
                    $attachment=$row['attachment'];
                    $mime->addAttachment($attachment, mime_content_type($attachment));
                }
                 $body = $mime->get();
                 $headers = $mime->headers($headers);
            } else {
                $headers = array ('From' => $from, 'To' => $to, 'Subject' => $subject,'Content-type' => 'text/html;charset=iso-8859-1');
                $body = $body;
            }   
        }

        $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
          array ('host' => $host,
            'port' => $port,
            'auth' => true,
            'username' => $username,
            'password' => $password));

        $mail=$smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
        if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
              echo "<p>Message not sent:".$mail->getMessage()."</p>";
              return $mail->getMessage();  
          } else {   
            //echo "<p>Message successfully sent!</p>";
            return 'sent';  
          }
    }
```

Comment: It looks like `mime_content_type()` is deprecated anyway (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php), try replacing it with Fileinfo functions as they mention in the docs. It might solve your problem in the process (though hard to say, because we don't know what your code looks like).

Comment: Try replacing PEAR with a php mail library such as phpMailer...? PEAR has a lot of code using deprecated functionalities. The libraries usually have methods for adding attachments as well, thus making it easier...

Comment: @Raphioly-San I use pear because i want the mails to go through smtp authentication.

Comment: @Mike I just posted the code... How would you suggest changing the  `$mime->addAttachment($attachment, mime_content_type($attachment)); `line to get it to work?

Comment: @Marcel e.g. PHPmailer can handle sending through SMTP (also SSL/TLS) as well and doesn't need any external library...

Comment: @Raphioly-San I did not know that... If needed I will make the change later. Thank you :)

Comment: @Mike I was able to find the solution with your help. If you post it as an answer, I will accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like [mime_content_type() is deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) anyway, try replacing it with [Fileinfo functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php) as they mention in the docs. It might solve your problem in the process (though hard to say, because we don't know what your code looks like).